# Doesn't have enough funds to send Tx - TestRPC and Metamask

Tags: web3js, truffle, testrpc, metamask

I'm testing and creating a smart contract to send some ether to one account using TestRPC, Truffle and Metamask.

I have a page with a button, when i click on the button it fires the event submitEtherWallet

```
submitEtherToWallet: function() {
    MyWallet.deployed().then(function(instance){

      return instance.sendTransaction({from: account, to: instance.address, value: web3.toWei(5, 'ether')});

    }).then(function(result) {
      App.basicInfoUpdate();
    });
  },
```

The method aparently is working well, because metamask open a popup to confirm the transacation.

[image]

After click to submit the transaction:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours stucked with this issue, I realized that aparently my metamask was running in a different instace of web3 than my testrpc, it's a weird situation.

Metamask was oppening the correct account popup to confirm the transaction, but in the backend metamask was trying to send the transaction with a different account, I don't know how this happened but I replaced my addEventListener back to the original from truffle webpack and aparently it fixed the issue.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source. If you find that your accounts don't appear or you have 0 MetaCoin, ensure you've configured that source properly. If using MetaMask, see the following link. Feel free to delete this warning. :) http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask")
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://127.0.0.1:9545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:9545"));
  }

  App.start();
});
```

As you can see in the printscreen, metamask was trying to send the transaction through the wallet "0xf9..." and not with the wallet that was in the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, in the code, that "from: account" refers to accounts[0] ?

Comment: Yes, it does. In the start function it fills the account with accounts[0], also I tried to change the account to accounts[0] and happened the samething.

Answer (score 0):

You can restart testrpc. I faced the same problem, restarting testrpc fixed the problem